# Choosing a Power BI Measure based on a slicer

Tags: powerbi, measure, slicers

I'm making a data report for my company which will have a slicer to select the quarter.  I have colmuns for Beginning balance, each of the three months within the quarter (Per1, Per2, and Per3), Quarter to Date, and Year to Date.  Right now, I have no problems getting the data into the right format.  I've got a report with a SUM measure for each month, and "Per" measures with Switch functions to choose which SUM measures are being used.

What I'd like to do is be able to change the column names from Per1, Per2 and Per3 to the actual month being displayed (April, May, June for example).

Is there a way to either change column heading so it displays the name of the measure being chosen?

Alternatively, is there a way to use the slicer to choose which SUM measures are pulled into the report?

Right now, it looks like this:
Beginning   Per1   Per2   Per3   QTD   YTD

I'd like it to look like this:
Beginning   Jan   Feb   Mar   QTD   YTD

I'd like to be able to change the months based on the selection of quarter in the slicer.

Answer (score 0):

In Visualizations(right menu) you can try to change the data in the fields Legend and Values and you can play with Filters as well.
If it doesn't work you can change the column name when you connect to the excel data, it will change only on the query not in the source.